# Google keeps returning Baidu certificate as its own

Tags: ssl, networking, https

I'm unable to access Google on my computer after moving to a new network. The failure seems to a combination of my Macbook and the network. My Iphone can access Google on the same network. My Macbook can access Google when using a VPN.

```
❯ curl https://www.google.com
curl: (60) SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name 'www.google.com'
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above
```

And the certificate I get from Google belongs to Baidu.

```py
import ssl
print(ssl.get_server_certificate(('www.google.com', 443)))
# use an online certificate decoder
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you believe that baidu certificate is associated in any way with the connection attempt to `www.google.com`? When I run that little python fragment I get a bogus certificate from google whose subject and issuer name OU say "No SNI provided; please fix your client." In fact I don't understand why the code doesn't just raise an exception instead of returning the bogus cert.

Comment: the python fragment does not produce the same result on my computer and your computer because we are using two different networks.

Comment: I'm not sure what "No SNI provided" means.

Comment: SNI means server name indication, it's an extension in TLS 1.2 but it might be required in TLS 1.3, I'm not expert in TLS 1.3 yet. In any event I can't think of any reason *not* to send it, so I don't understand why the python SSL library doesn't send it there. It might just be a (minor) bug in the python SSL library.